# Join 2 tables with string_id instead of jointable

Tags: sql-server, string, t-sql, inner-join, unnest

I want to join 2 tables but there is no join table between them... I usually use STRING_SPLIT but in this case, I can't figure it out. Maybe I'm just tired... Could you help me please ?

```
CREATE TABLE ##Provider
(
  id INT,
  p_name VARCHAR(50),
  list_id_dep VARCHAR(250)
)

CREATE TABLE ##Department
(
  id INT,
  d_name VARCHAR(50)
)

INSERT INTO ##Provider (id, p_name, list_id_dep) VALUES 
    (1, 'toto', '/10/11/12/'),
    (2, 'tata', '/09/');

INSERT INTO ##Department (id, d_name) VALUES 
    (9, 'dep9')
    ,(10, 'dep10')
    ,(11, 'dep11')
    ,(12, 'dep12');
```

What I want is :

```
id | p_name | d_name
--------------------------
1  | toto   | dep10
1  | toto   | dep11
1  | toto   | dep12
2  | tata   | dep09
```

I've tried :

```
select *
from ##Provider p 
inner join ##Department d on STRING_SPLIT(p.list_id_dep, '/') = ???
```

```
select *
from ##Provider p 
inner join STRING_SPLIT(p.list_id_dep, '/') dep ON dep.value = ???
```

```
select *
from ##Provider p, ##Department d
where (select value from STRING_SPLIT(p.list_id_dep, '/')) = d.id
```

```
select *
from ##Provider p, ##Department d
where d.id in (select value from STRING_SPLIT(p.list_id_dep, '/'))
```

Maybe STRING_SPLIT is not the right way to do it...

Thanks !

Comment: Please correct your logic.  First you break your `p.list_id_dep` into rows, then you `JOIN`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a lateral join to unnest the string - in SQL Server, this is implented with `cross apply`. Then, you can bring the `department` table with a regular join:

```
select p.id, p.p_name, d.d_name
from ##provider p 
cross apply string_split(p.list_id_dep, '/') x
inner join ##department d on d.id = x.value
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ef79386122812636192630ce4dccd82d)**:

```
id | p_name | d_name
-: | :----- | :-----
 1 | toto   | dep10 
 1 | toto   | dep11 
 1 | toto   | dep12 
 2 | tata   | dep9
```